# Manuscript was returned by the Editor to include more data, should I prepare "Response to Editor"?

Tags: publications, peer-review

I have submitted a manuscript that was returned by the Editor mainly because there is "no enough data" on the manuscript. The manuscript is a bit shorter and to-the-point. Of course, I have been also asked to revise the English and proofread it.

Now I have addressed the editor request, should I just re-submit the manuscript alone or I need to include a "response to the Editor" as well?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean "dispute the editor" then I don't recommend it. For the most part, if you don't generally follow the editor's advice as best you can, then you are likely to be rejected at the end.

But if your response is of the form "these are the changes...", then yes, include a response, as they will make the editor's job easier and more likely to give you a fair and accurate review.

There may be a difference of opinion, of course, about how much data is enough, but that can be worked out if everyone stays positive. Just don't try to tell an editor, who has all the power, how to do the job. That isn't a path to success.

Answer (score 0):

Did the editor decide on "reject and resubmit", or simply returned the manuscript to you? In the former case, if you resubmit, you'll need a fresh submission in the Editorial Management System; in the latter, you can use your original submission.

In the former case, a "response to editor" is not necessary; just write what you need to in the cover letter. In the latter, you'll need to attach one because you probably won't get to submit a cover letter.

In both cases you should submit a response - it helps the editor remember what happened to your paper (especially if it took you a long time to make the revision). It's true the editor can just check the logs in the editorial management system, but that's more troublesome.